# recommend a book on mid-game plan and board evaluation

Tags: strategy, books, evaluation, planning

Could someone recommend a book on mid-game strategy please?

Things I am especially interested in are

1. Make plans (and foresee opponents plan and stop it)
2. Evaluate current position
3. Evaluate positions at the end of calculation

I guess 2 is somewhat blended in 1 and 3. My problem is that even though I may be able to do some evaluation for the current position, it's very hard to do the same at the end of each variation I calculated. So I'm looking for both a more involved way to analyse current position and also a quick way to roughly evaluate positions down the line. (Or maybe practice is the only way?)

Thanks.

(Not really interested in tactics as this is not my bottleneck)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's your rating?

Comment: Never played at a club or tourney, but playing white I'm beating my phone at 1800 setting (I have no idea on black opening)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["***Reassess Your Chess***"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1890085138) by Jeremy Silman is a modern classic on planning and imbalances.

Comment: Thanks to all suggestions. I searched all of them. I finally bought this one mainly because of kindle availability.

Comment: As has been said, How to Reassess your Chess by Silman 100%

Answer (score 4):

"The Art of The Middle Game" by Keres and Kotov comes to mind.  And an older book,"Strategy and Tactics in Chess" by Max Euwe, was long considered a classic in this area. Of course study always has to be combined with practice.

Comment: "Judgment and Planning in Chess", also by Euwe, and "How to Win in The Middle Game of Chess" by Al Horowitz are two more books covering this area.

Comment: And I'd be remiss if I didn't also mention Euwe's two volume treatise on the subject, "The Middle Game", co-authored with Hans Kramer.

Answer (score 1):

Two interesting books have been published recently that might be helpful to you:

- [Winning Chess Manoeuvres](https://www.newinchess.com/Winning_Chess_Manoeuvres-p-9015.html)
- [Chess Structures - A Grandmaster Guide](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/2/235/chess_structures_-_a_grandmaster_guide_by_mauricio_flores_rios/)

Both concentrate on conveying "chess culture" - the knowledge how to handle certain typical positions and situations. This should be a good way to tackle your point 1.

Precise evaluation only comes with experience, practice and knowledge. Possibly you will have to train calculation instead of tactics.

Answer (score 1):

Chess Strategy for Club Players, The Road to Positional Advantage by Herman Grooten is worth looking at.

Comment: This is the only one with an electronic version!